# Comparing two time series data sets. What statistical analysis to use?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, anova, continuous-data

I have two time series data sets. One with treatment and one without treatment. I want to test if the slope of the two data sets are significantly different.

Which statistical analysis do I use for this?

Comment: Maybe something like the R package Causal Impact: https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html

Comment: I’d look at Mann-Kendall analyses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to go that far, you might fit bivariate state-space models with a common slope and two individual slopes, and compare the fits. Depending on what your data looks like (same units?, same time data points?) you might test the differences for a trend. I think your question is too general to venture a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

By plotting them you can get some idea on how different the data is.
Apply SMA on both data and then plot to compare.